# i want my vs code to create the executables for c++ files in a separate folder and run from there

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am using vs code since a while for c++ development . But when a directory has 10 to 15 c++ files the file directory looks super messy and it's annoying to delete them once in a while . Is there a way so that by default vs code create the .out executable file in a separate folder . I am using vs code on ubuntu 20.04 lts . I am attaching details of my c++ build system for more clarity . Please help me with this .

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: cpp build active file",
      "command": "/bin/cpp",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "compiler: /bin/cpp"
    }
  ]
}
```

what to do to solve the following issue ?

Comment: Change the `${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}` line to specify where you want the output file to be placed.

Comment: @NathanPierson can you please share exactly the line to be added there if $HOME/somefolder is my directory where i want my executable to be stored ?

Comment: use a propper build system like CMAKE for build. VS code even has an extension for cmake.